# Update table column line by line based on yes/no values from combo box

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I am very new to Access and VBA but what i'm trying to do is simple:

I have a table which i want to show in a form, i have put said table in a subform box.
I want to have a column in which i want to update the status based on options from the combo box (yes/ no/ maybe).

So as shown in the picture: i want to select a line in the subform and update the column status by selecting an option in the combo box.

[image]

Comment: Need a field in table to receive data. Either set that field as a combobox (I never do this in table) or use a form object instead of table in subform and build a combobox on form.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the selected record in the subform in the `AfterUpdate` event of the combo box.

```
Private Sub cboStatus_AfterUpdate()
    subForm1.Form!Status = cboStatus
End Sub
```

This assumes that your combo box control is named `cboStatus`, your subform is named `subForm1`, and the field you want to update is named **Status**.  It also assumes you aren't using numerical ID's as foreign keys for your values.

You will only be able to update one row at a time.

---

*Beyond the scope of your question....*

There are numerous other ways to develop an interface to edit the row.  One way is to modify the field *Lookup* properties in the table.  You can change the Display Control to a Combo Box, set the Row Source type to Value List, and then set the Row Source to a list of possible values separated by semicolon.

[image]

Now whenever you open that table in a datasheet view (like the example on your subform) a dropdown will appear in that column.  A user can edit directly in that view without requiring a separate combo box control.

[image]